# Configure a desktop IE shortcut to find and focus to existing window

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, shortcuts

Using Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9 (or above) I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut to a particular webpage. The trick is, if the user already has that webpage open in any IE window, I need the shortcut to focus to that window instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This powershell script looks at all current IE URLs, then if none have google open, it opens google.com, otherwise, does nothing. You need to change "*google" to "*yourbaseURLname" and "www.google.com" to "www.yourwebsite.com". (last 5 lines of script)

Save this as a .ps1 file.

```
Function GetCurrentIEURL
{
    $IEObjs = @()
    $ShellWindows = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()

    Foreach($IE in $ShellWindows)
    {
        $FullName = $IE.FullName
        If($FullName -ne $NULL)
        {
            $FileName = Split-Path -Path $FullName -Leaf

            If($FileName.ToLower() -eq "iexplore.exe")
            {
                $Title = $IE.LocationName
                $URL = $IE.LocationURL
                $IEObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Title = $Title; URL = $URL}
                $IEObjs += $IEObj
            }
        }
    }

    $IEObjs
}

$CurrentIEURL = GetCurrentIEURL

if ($CurrentIEURL -NotContains "*google")
{
    $IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
    $IE.navigate2("www.google.com")
    $IE.visible=$true
}
```